# GetWebResponse very slow on windows7

Tags: c#

I have tried all the settings, i found on internet to make the C# webclient fast on a Windows7 machine
to no avail. The same exe on Windows XP machine responds in less 100ms for every request.

I have overridden the GetWebRequest function in the derived class of 
**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol**

```
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        //ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
        HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 4096;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.Proxy = HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

        return (WebRequest)request;
    }
```

protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
        {

```
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        //HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
        //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)base.GetWebResponse(request);
        return response;
    }
```

I have also added the socket trace settings in the machine.config .Net4.0 folder
and it always waits on the below statement for 7-15 seconds in the output window

**System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [6088] Socket#54042743::Receive()**

Hope some champion has resolved this

Answer (score 1):

Try using the GetResponse class and check if you find some difference:

```
HttpWebRequest wrequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(objeto.Url);

//Get Response
HttpWebResponse wresp = (HttpWebResponse) wrequest.GetResponse();

//get Response Stream
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wresp.GetResponseStream());

//Get string content
string respuestastring = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: FYI , when i run the Fiddler tool, the response is quick as well. 
so i am sure this is to something do with the proxy


 protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
            return (WebRequest)request;
        }

Comment: protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest wrequest)
        {

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wrequest.GetResponse();
            //get Response Stream
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            //Get string content
            string respuestastring = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return response;
        }

Comment: No. In IE settings, 1. Automatically detect settings ,2. use automatic config,3. Use proxy server for your LAN are all disabled

Comment: Hi Carlos, what do you mean by GetResponse class, can u give some example, i am new to c#

Comment: My answer, it's the most common way to make a http petition in c#. I was telling you to try it. Dont need to override anything in windows 7. Http petitions should have same speed in xp and win 7.  Use my code. Change the objeto.URL by the url string and debug it ;)

Comment: Carlos, where do i change it ? sorry i am not getting it. can you please specify the location. is it in the derived class of System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol constructor

Comment: Just Import system.net, copy and paste my code and change objeto.url with your destination url and debug the code.

Comment: The below line 

HttpWebResponse wresp = (HttpWebResponse) wrequest.GetResponse(); 

takes around 7 seconds to responds to respond. FYI, In IE the response is immediate.

Comment: i have replaced the objeto.URL with my server url.

Comment: Hi Carlos, i created a new sample and have used your above code by replacing the url and HttpWebResponse wresp = (HttpWebResponse) wrequest.GetResponse(); takes around 7 seconds to respond. again waiting on the socket.Receive as i can see in my network trace

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and it turned out that I didn't close the web request, so when I fired a few in a row, I hit the maximum number of connections allowed by the host and it wouldn't continue until the first requests timed out. So try manually closing your requests or, better, wrap the variable declaration for your request into a `using` directive.